# Reshape Data for Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, data-analysis, reshape

I would like to transform my data below using the R language:

[Data Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BUhP.png)

To the final format below:

[Data Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLbPD.png)

My data goes to the year 2017, the images are just a snippet of the data.
The main goal is to structure the data to create a time series. Another approach, would it be possible to create a time series with the original data?
I did several searches but I didn't find something specific for my case. I tried using the "melt" function but I was not successful. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is a "reshape wide to long". There should be literally thousands of examples here at Stackoverflow such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Comment: thank you very much, i managed to apply the idea of ​​the exemple and apply it to my data! It worked out!